# Not retaining values after save

Tags: jqgrid

In my application I am using jqGrid to display the data from database, user can update the values and save the data in database. I have a paging in the grid. 
I want to implement 2 things --

--- After I save values in the database, jqGrid columns become blank. I want to retain the values in column after save.
--- When I update the values on one page and goes to second page and again I come back to first page, I want to retain the values on the first page.

Is that possible?

Comment: You wrote "After I save values in the database, jqGrid columns become blank". It means that you implemented editing in the wrong way. Which editing mode you use? jqGrid should display the modified data after saving the data. You should include the code which you use or prepare the demo which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I am using inline edit and bulk  edit. For bulk save the code is --- function saveRows() {
            var grid = $("#grid");
            var ids = grid.jqGrid('getDataIDs');

            for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
                grid.jqGrid('saveRow', ids[i]);
            }
        };              For saving I have method in my controller.

Comment: You should click "edit" link below of the question and modify the text by including more full code which you use. Calling of `saveRow` in the loop for all rows have typically no sense because `saveRow` will work only on rows which are *in editing mode*. Do you call `editRow` for every line of the grid before? Why? One edit typically one row at once. If you edited data locally (on grid which has `datatype: "local"`) then you can use `grid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "data")` to get the current (modified) data. you can send the data to the server via `$.ajax` call.

Comment: Thanks... this is working.

Comment: You are welcome! I posted the same information as the answer. You can close the question by "accepting" the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you edited data locally (on grid which has `datatype: "local"`) then you can use `grid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "data")` to get the **current** (modified) data. you can send the data to the server via `$.ajax` call.